# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library erro when clicking on new material or rendered or material preview

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders

When i click on new material or rendered or material preview it gives me a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error [image]

Comment: Did you installed Blender via the Windows Installer (.msi) or are you using the Portable version (.zip) ? Are your graphic drivers up to date ?

Comment: i'm new in blender .so i don't know what do you mean by (msi) or (zip). yes my graphic card is updated.